# Angular npm install application fails

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, angular-cli, grpc

I get a similar error to a whole lot of other stack threads. However after trying many of the suggested solutions I am still stuck. I am running

```
npm install
```

in a cloned git project folder when trying to run an angular application. This yields the following error:

```
 > grpc@1.10.1 install /Users/my_usrname/my_project/node_modules/grpc

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
gyp  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
 ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oe
../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.cc:23:10: fatal error: l: Failed to e
      'src/core/lib/gpr/useful.h' file not found
    #include "src/core/lib/gpr/useful.h"

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    1 error generated.

make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/Users/my_usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/myusrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/my_usrname/my_project-master/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build -- <pre><code>library=static_library`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

    npm ERR! 

    npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.

    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

    npm ERR!     /Users/my_usrname/.npm/_logs/2019-03-21T19_25_09_711Z-debug.log
```

I have node version `v10.15.3`, npm verison `6.9.0`.

About angular:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 10.15.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.4
```

I have tried uninstalling node, restarting computer and reinstalling node as some have suggested. Installed node-gyp globaly as I found in another answer.

I am able to run this angular application however, from following angular quick start at https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Did you try installing grpc@1.10.1 first and then nom install? Because from error log it seems that binaries for grpc is not found.

Comment: Same issue here. Tried to solve with many workarounds, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues here. First, grpc@1.10.1 is a fairly old version of the library, and it does not have support for Node 10, which is newer. If you are explicitly depending on that version of grpc or one of your dependencies is, you should try to update the dependency or get your dependency to do so. Alternatively, I believe that version of grpc supports Node 8, so you can downgrade your Node version to get it working.

Second, I am guessing from the mention of Angular that your are going to want to run this on a browser client. That will not work; grpc simply does not work on browsers. If you are using grpc directly you may be able to use `grpc-web` instead on the browser.